# How do I add a Title to a powershell window?

Tags: powershell

I have many PowerShell windows open, with a command history specific for a task.

In the good old Batch file days I would use `Title finance dpt` or `Title Email Admin`.  How can I accomplish this in PS?

Comment: @buzz3791 The UserVoice.com link in comment from '18 is no longer available.  Can you delete the comment?  We can't edit your comment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
PS C:\> $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "New Window Title"
```

You can also throw this in your profile if it's something you want on each new PS window.

Check out the TechNet article [*Customizing the Windows PowerShell Console*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156814.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the title when you spawn a process:

```
$StartInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$StartInfo.FileName = "$pshome\powershell.exe"
$StartInfo.Arguments = "-NoExit -Command `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle=`'Your Title Here`'"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($StartInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is to use the following command in the PowerShell window:-

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Some Name'
```

You can also use the following command in the **Command prompt(cmd)** or **RunAs Dialog Box** for getting the PowerShell Window with desired Title in the traditional CMD styled window.

```
cmd /k PowerShell -NoExit -Command "& {$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Powershell'}"
```

P.S: Its like traditional CMD with PowerShell features and Syntax Highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If its your own console you wnat to customise then the [following article](http://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/) at how-to-geek has the detail you need.  Quite a few steps but worth it.